# Pure JavaScript alternative to jQuery's .html()

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following code is used to ajax-load a div.

The only issue I have with it is that `.html()` renders *raw* html, and so I thought it might be a good idea to replace that with a pure JS alternative so that my view is clean of any escaping raw html.

I'd love to hear your thoughts about this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('.ajax_load').each(function(index, element) {
        var url = $(element).data('remote-url')
        if (url) {
          $.get(url, function(responseText) {
            $(element).html(responseText);
          })
        } else {
          console.log("missing url for ajax!")
        }
      })
    })
```

Comment: Nearly every line uses jQuery, not just the part that handles the response. So you will probably be loading the jQuery library anyway. You might as well use it. Try using `$(element).text(responseText)` instead if you just want to disable rendering raw html.

Comment: You could always look at the jQuery source files

Comment: `element.innerHTML = '<some divs>'` used in your site footer will basically remove the need for `ready` and many other old and not very performant jQuery methods.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent):

> The Node.textContent property represents the text content of a node
>   and its descendants.

```
element.textContent = responseText;
```

Answer (score 7):

jQuery's `.html()` method takes a string and runs that string through the HTML parser so that any HTML markup can be processed and the DOM updated. jQuery's `.text()` method also takes a string, but that string (even if it contains HTML) is not passed to the HTML parser for processing and any markup is escaped and included as textual content in the page.

---

If you would like to not use jQuery, you can accomplish the same thing as `.html()` with the DOM `.innerHTML`(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) property.

If you would like to accomplish the same thing as `.text()`, you can use the proprietary/legacy `.innerText` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/innerText) property or the standard `textContent` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) DOM property (but the latter is not supported in IE until IE 9).

Comment: `innerText` is not standard, it's a IE thingy

Comment: It was created by MS, but is well supported in all major browsers. But, no, it's not a standard. Just a de facto standard.

Comment: No, Firefox no longer supports innerText -- the standard way is to use textContent. Make the change, and I'll give you an upvote.

Comment: I've added textContent, but be warned that this doesn't work in IE8.

Comment: Most places have dropped IE8 support now that MS has dropped support for most versions as well. You shouldn't be held hostage to legacy/proprietary thinking, just because you were in the past. It would be better to polyfill textContent, than to use innerText

Comment: Saying "Most places" is purely speculative. In my work (travelling the country and working with large corporations), IE 8 is still alive and well due to internal applications that were built to support it.  Polyfill is not an option in these closed environments.

Comment: Polyfill is always an option; it adds no overhead. However, I'd like to know why you undid my edit that improved your post's legibility?

Comment: I'm telling you that in many environments, polyfill is NOT an option. Why are you arguing this fact?  And, I didn't "undo" you edits, I edited your edit because I felt adding brackets detracted from the legibility.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I didn't add brackets, I used markdown to turn your text into links. Also, I'm not sure you understand how polyfills work. It just checks for the existence of a feature, and recreates it in javascript for the legacy browsers. It's not like a plugin or some flash applet, etc.

Comment: I am well aware of how polyfills work. I'm telling you that at some of the largest corporations in America, proprietary applications were built to run on IE8 and still need to be supported. These applicaitons are considered legacy at this point and going back and adding polyfills to them is not an option. But, you seem to want to argue a fact that you have no direct knowledge of. Strange. Also, I am happy with my post as it is. Please stop editing it. Down vote it if you don't like it or post your own answer. You seem to be very argumentative about issues that you are not direclty involved in.

Comment: @ScottMarcus you do realize this is the internet.. everybody is directly involved in this answer.

Comment: My initial revision was approved because the community agreed that it improved legibility. Your post is hard to track with the long URLs. I was only trying to help out. Please don't be so negative.

Comment: @SterlingArcher You do realize that it was my answer and my experience that I am conveying, right? Not, the Internet's.